# org.glassfish.apf.AnnotationInfo@18c52fe exception

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish

I am trying to compile a source code written by someone else, to execute on glass fish. But the get the below expection when I try to execute on glassfish 3.1.2 environment. I have added the lucene-core.jar, glassfish runtime library.

SEVERE: Exception while deploying the app [NOTDISCLOSED] : org/apache/lucene/search/SortComparatorSourceat org.glassfish.apf.AnnotationInfo@18c52fe org/apache/lucene/search/SortComparatorSourceat org.glassfish.apf.AnnotationInfo@18c52fe at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:367) at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:375) at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:289) at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:217) at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:134) at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.processAnnotations(Archivist.java:598) at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:442) at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:429) at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readRestDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:405) at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:380) at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:243) at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:252) at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:213) at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:165) at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:185) at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:94) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:827) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:769) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:368) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240) at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212) at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195) at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860) at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757) at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056) at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229) at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137) at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104) at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90) at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79) at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54) at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59) at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71) at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532) at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/search/SortComparatorSource at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266) at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.TypeUtil.getMethod(TypeUtil.java:399) at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.MethodDescriptor.getMethod(MethodDescriptor.java:298) at org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.annotation.handlers.TransactionAttributeHandler.processAnnotation(TransactionAttributeHandler.java:101) at org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.annotation.handlers.AbstractAttributeHandler.processAnnotation(AbstractAttributeHandler.java:183) at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:344) ... 46 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.search.SortComparatorSource at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClassData(ASURLClassLoader.java:808) at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClass(ASURLClassLoader.java:696) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356) ... 53 more

Please provide some suggestion as to what I might be missing or what might have gone wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, sad to see no help, but finally I figured out the solution, thought of posting it as this may be of help to someone. The problem is because the code compiles on Java EE Glassfish 2.1 but not Glassfish 3.1 Lucene packages are outdated. Updating Lucene causing issues, so I have to get rid of depreciated APIs used in the code, then compile.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after trying lots of things like cleaning caches, other JDKs version, etc. I solved it by restarting the OS